# file upload functionality using json with spring rest webservices in mobile application

Tags: json, spring, web-services

Right now we have a web application which upload a file using multipart in spring . now we are converting it as a rest webservices with JSON to a mobile application. how to send file details to rest webservice controller  using json.

Comment: { "fileName" : "the file name", "contents" : "the file contents" }  in this how we will get the content. content may be image file, pdf or doc , how to get their contents to pass as a json.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple

This is stateless.
Send JSON similar to this:

{ "fileName" : "the file name",
  "contents" : "the file contents"
}

Be sure to use JSON escaping of the file contents and the file name.

### Not Great

This requires state (not a good thing for a rest controller).

Call1: Post to .../beginUpload
Description: starts a file upload.
Parameter:
  filename
ReturnValue: some identifer (called FileId below).

Call2: Post to .../fileContents
Desciption: adds some contents to an already open file.
Call this one or more times until the file contents are fully transferred.
Parameters: 
  fileId, contents.
ReturnValue: success / failure

Call3: Post to .../endUpload
Description: ends a file upload.
Parameter:
  fileId
ReturnValue: success / failure

Challenge: the rest server may need to timeout uploads that have not had a call to .../fileContents in x minutes.

### Different

Have the mobile device send an email containing the file to be uploaded.
Implement something to monitor the emailbox to which the file upload emails are sent and do "the right stuff".